# How do I prevent search terms from being copied between applications?

Tags: macos, search, text

If I have a search field open in Xcode and Safari at the same time, switching between the apps will copy the search term from one app to the other.

To reproduce this:

1. Open a webpage in Safari, and press Cmd-F to search the page, but don't type anything
2. Go to the Find Navigator in Xcode, and type "xcodesearch"
3. Use the app switcher to go to Safari

"xcodesearch" ends up in Safari's Find search field. Is there a setting that controls this? I don't want this to happen.

OS X 10.8.4, MacBook Air

Comment: Came here to ask the same question. Happening between Coda and Text Wrangler for me. So annoying. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a solution yet. I haven't updated to Mavericks, so I don't know if the situation is different there.

Comment: *It's not a bug, it's a feature !* Seriously, this feature appeared quite a few years ago. So there is a solution : downgrade to a quite old system, maybe Jaguar. I don't advise it.

Comment: [MacOS Catalina] This is the most stupid `feature` one could imagine, so much so I consider it a `bug`.  The number of times I have to re-enter what I'm searching for here because I searched for something else somewhere else in the interm is ridiculous. Still scratching my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an answer the best I can with the research I've done. This is a relatively new addition in the OS. If I am not mistaken since 10.8 and what happened is Apple changed the Helper daemon.

I do not know of a way to configure the helperd parameters. My recommendation is to give Apple feedback via http://apple.com/feedback/ and ask that they give the ability to toggle it or remove it all together.

Additionally ask the mad scientists here to include the functionality 
http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html

Comment: This "shared search" feature was added quite a few years ago. It is older than Mac OS X 10.8. I am almost sure that this feature is it *at least as old as Mac OS X 10.6*.

Comment: Feedback to Apple made.